# using powershell to gather logged on user names on remote computers?

Tags: powershell

```
$MachineList = Get-Content -Path "E:\ps\comp list\Test Computers.txt"; # One system name per line 
foreach ($Machine in $MachineList)
{ 
($Machine + ": " + @(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Machine -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -erroraction silentlycontinue)[0].UserName); 

Write-Output ($Machine + ": " + @(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Machine -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -erroraction silentlycontinue)[0].UserName) | Out-File "E:\ps\comp output\Test Computers.txt" -Append
}
```

**Update:** Here's the working script, thanks all for the help! :) It pulls in a list of computers prints to the screen and then also writes them to a file.

I found this powershell code and it works but I'd like it to display the machine name in front of the username when it displays. How can I get it to do that?

So like -

MachineName: Username

I'm a powershell newb... any help would be appreciated! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$MachineList = Get-Content -Path c:\ListOfMachines.txt; # One system name per line
foreach ($Machine in $MachineList){
    ($Machine + ": " + @(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Machine -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem)[0].UserName);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way for it to skip the machine names that it can't find instead of giving me red error codes? Or filter them out somehow?

Comment: Add -erroraction silentlycontinue to skip the errors - see my answer for use.

Comment: Thanks Dave! Never mind my last question it was confusing... But is there a way I could make it write the output to a file?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Get-Content -Path c:\ListOfMachines.txt | % {
  Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $_ -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -erroraction silentlycontinue | % {
    "$($_.Name): $($_.username)"
  }
}
```